# How do I switch buffers quickly?

Tags: key-bindings, buffers, cycling

In vanilla Emacs, I have to do `C-x b` and then manually type out the buffer name to switch. If I forget the  name of the buffer, I have to hit `TAB` to list possible completions. Is there anything I can do to make this process faster?

Comment: This should get marked Community Wiki.  But Emacs already has a giant wiki.  For instance, my top Google result is this page on [Switching Buffers](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers).  CW-style questions feel, to me, particularly out of place on emacs.SE.

Comment: I like using `C-x C-<left/right>` to switch buffers quickly. When needing to switch to "farther" buffer, I use `IBuffer`.

Comment: I use 'C-x x' to switch buffers (with helm and with caps mapped to control). I've never felt comfortable typing 'C-x b'.

Comment: [How can I more easily switch between buffers in Emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7394289/324105), [Emacs: help me understand file/buffer management](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3145332/324105), along with numerous linked Q&As from each.

Comment: Use one of the solutions in the answers and don't use C-x b. 3 keys are too many for such a frequent operation. I personally use a single key, the right windows key which I don't use otherwise.

Comment: @purple_arrows: I agree with you on both counts: (1) The Emacs Wiki page about this is the right place to get into it and (2) this is not a great question for emacs.SE. This is more of a Reddit thread or an Emacs-Wiki discussion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a simple Q&A, but is essentially a list-your-favorite XYZ poll. There is more "I like!!" than there are useful reasons-why in the resulting answers. It is more appropriate on an opinion/discussion site than emacs.SE.

Comment: Emacs is full of awful ux design decisions...

Answer (score 68):

I've recently started using `C-x <left>` and `C-x <right>`. Those are both standard Emacs bindings—nothing to configure. Left takes you back to the previous buffer (initially the same as `C-x b RET`) but doing it again takes you to the 3rd most recently visited buffer. If you're popping back and forth between 3 or 4 buffers a lot then I find it a lot easier than trying to remember buffer names.

Also I just discovered `C-x C-<left>` and `C-x C-<right>` are bound to the same functions so that you can just hold down the control key and alternate between x and the arrows to flip through buffers. Pretty nice!

Comment: I agree with you! I'm a newcomer to emacs, and don't want to be overloaded with extra packages and yet-more-configurations. This solution works for me! :D

Comment: C-x C-<left> and C-x C-<right> for the win! I used to have prev/next buffer bound to C-S-<left>/<right>. But somehow I find typing C-x C-left even easier then using two meta keys. C-S is awkward to press.

Comment: Nice!  I learned these bindings a week ago, thought how awesome they were, and then forgot what they are.  Couldn't find them on the net for a week, until now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 55):

There is [ido](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_buffer_switching.html) mode that should help.

**EDIT:**

put this in your init file, to activate ido mode by default:

`(ido-mode 1)`

Now, `C-x b` will show you a list of candidates.

Put this in your init file, if you prefer the items being displayed vertically:

`(setq ido-separator "\n")`

Courtesy of [ergoemacs](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_buffer_switching.html)

Let me also suggest this [post](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_next_prev_user_buffer.html) talking about switch to previous/next buffer.

Comment: We should probably try to get most of the important information in that post as a response to this question. That way future users will not have to chase links to possibly dead sites.

Comment: @nixeagle I made some edits, I hope the most important informations are present.

Comment: I upvoted yours as it is complete now, but I will wait a few days before I accept in case others come with different and or better answers. Thanks!

Comment: @nixeagle it's nothing!

Comment: @nixeagle have you found a better answer?

Answer (score 46):

You could use [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm).

In my setup, I have switched `C-x b` for `M-l`. This allied with `helm-buffers-list`, makes the process pretty fast, at least for me.

Comment: This is basically the best answer now.  Sure, you can still use `ido` or `iswitchb` or `icicles`, stuff like that, but they are basically obsoleted by Helm.  Yeah, `ace-jump-buffer` is cool, but it's not as fast as Helm, because before you know what key to press, you have to find the buffer in the list.  Helm lets you narrow down the list with a few keystrokes which you already know (like the name of the buffer).  I use `C-TAB` to switch buffers, load recent files, bookmarks, etc.  Nothing's faster.

Comment: +1 for `helm`. But I prefer using `helm-mini`, which also shows you `Recentf` to `helm-buffers-list`.

Comment: There is also [ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) with `ivy-switch-buffer`.

Comment: I find ivy much faster than helm, so I recommend it over helm.

Answer (score 10):

Just to add tweaks that I use with already mentioned [Ido](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings):

```
(require 'ido)
(require 'ido-hacks)
(require 'flx-ido)
(require 'ido-vertical-mode)

(ido-mode 1)
(flx-ido-mode 1)
(ido-hacks-mode 1)
(ido-everywhere 1)
(ido-vertical-mode 1)

(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t
      ido-use-filename-at-point 'guess
      ido-vertical-define-keys 'C-n-C-p-up-down-left-right))
```

I'm also using [`ace-window`](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window) to switch between buffers together with [`ace-jump-mode`](https://github.com/winterTTr/ace-jump-mode) to *jump* between visible windows. Comes with some getting used to but worth trying.

I have combined it with [`key-chord-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/KeyChord) and hit `so` for quick jump:

```
(key-chord-define-global "so" 'ace-window)
```

All of the above mentioned packages are available via the package manager from Melpa.

Comment: I've edited your answer to replace `use-package` with `require` to prevent confusion. In the given example, there is no specific need for a user to install an additional package to implement that solution.

Comment: I'd suggest not to use letter combinations that occur frequently in English (assuming that you type mainly in English in emacs) as key-chords. In my opinion "so" is very easy to trigger unintentionally when you are typing stuff like "so", "some", "personal", etc very fast.

Answer (score 10):

As @kuanyui says in a comment, `next-buffer` & `previous-buffer` are very quick, if you have only a few buffers to cycle among. (For more than a few, and for more buffer-choosing features, I use [`icicle-buffer`](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Buffer-Name_Input).)

However, by default, *`next-buffer` and `previous-buffer` are on a prefix key, `C-x`*.

That means that **they are not repeatable**: you cannot just hit `C-x <right> <right> <right>...`. You must instead either bind these commands to different, repeatable keys, or you must use `C-x <right> C-x <right> C-x <right>...`, which is not very quick.

For repeatable versions of these commands, load library [`misc-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/misc-cmds.el) and remap the vanilla, unrepeatable versions to the repeatable ones defined there:

```el
(global-set-key [remap previous-buffer] 'previous-buffer-repeat)
(global-set-key [remap next-buffer]     'next-buffer-repeat)
```

(Similarly, in the same library you will find a version of `undo` that is repeatable even when on a prefix key: `undo-repeat`.)

---

BTW, you can make pretty much *any* command repeatable (even on a prefix key), by using function `repeat-command` (from [`misc-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/misc-cmds.el)).  This is all that was needed to define the repeatable version of `next-buffer`:

```el
(defun previous-buffer-repeat ()
  "Switch to the previous buffer in the selected window.
You can repeat this by hitting the last key again..."
  (interactive)
  (require 'repeat nil t) ; Library `repeat.el' is in Emacs 22.1 and later
  (repeat-command 'next-buffer))
```

Comment: ...or simply bind next/previous buffer to `C-,` and `C-.` to gain repeatability, and while you're on it anyway, set `C-x.` and `C-x,` to `other-window` and `(lambda()(interactive)(other-window -1))`. Cycling windows probably needs repeatability less, and you get away in a minute, without extra packages.

Comment: @AndreasSpindler: You can of course put any command on a repeatable key and thus make it repeatable. *That's not the point.* Repeatable keys are few, and unbound ones are getting rarer. This is about how to **make a command repeatable when it is on a prefix key**.

Comment: I unterstood your post, but referred more or less to the topic of this thread "How do I switch buffers quickly?". For this purpose I found your tip to use `next-buffer` and `previous-buffer` the best solution, independently from any specific key binding. Therefore my comment.

Comment: @AndreasSpindler: Got it; thx.

Comment: This is great, I many times need repeatable commands even when they have prefix keys. That said, I found prev/next buffer defaults to C-x C-left and C-x C-right which allows you to old C, and just repeat pressing x-left and x-right. Which is not too bad as default.

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned `iswitchb` yet. It may not be as powerful as `ido`, but long before `ido-mode` was born `iswitchb-mode` was already standard for emacs, and it is still useful nowadays.
To try it just put

```
(iswitchb-mode 1)
```

into your .emacs or activate via `M-x iswitchb-mode`.

Comment: `iswitchb` is obsolete as of Emacs 24.4. All of its functionality is available via `ido` now.

Comment: @Tyler I like the default look of iswitchb better, because it's more colorful, prettier. Maybe ido can be configured to look the same, but there is no point (at least for me) while iswitchb is available.

Answer (score 7):

Use [helm-buffer-list or helm-mini](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-6) for visually selecting buffer entry and fuzzy matching. It can do a lot of things outside of switching buffers. You should see the demo in the link.

Answer (score 7):

Others have discussed packages that are useful to make life easier with regards to buffer/window/frame switching.  (I personally use `helm` which is phenomenal.)  I want to discuss simpler changes that can make for a more enjoyable Emacs experience.

For me, the solution to my buffer/frame woes (because I think `C-x o` is the worst) was not a package; it was simply:

- mapping `C-;` to `other-window` (cycling through windows)
- mapping `C-'` to `other-frame` (cycling through frames).  I actually started using frames a lot more after adding this shortcut).
- mapping other easy single-keystroke key-bindings to simple, custom functions for manipulating buffers in the visible frame.  Examples include: throwing a buffer to the other window (in a 2-window set-up), toggling between the current buffer and last buffer in a given window, burying the other buffer (this one is great for replacing the `help` window that pops up (when reading man pages, apropos, etc) with whatever window was previously visible).

I also thought I'd share a few thoughts on key-bindings which newbies might find helpful.  (Sorry if this is the wrong place.)  I don't have specific suggestions but, rather, a "philosophy" that lets me maintain an effective set of keybindings for myself.

1. Unfrequently used commands do not deserve easy key-bindings.

   - Download `keyfreq.el` and see what you *really* use a lot.  I use a survival-of-the-fittest method to decide which commands are awarded the most valuable real-estate on my keyboard.
   - Don't be afraid to get rid of the default Emacs keybindings, some of which are just absurd.  `C-\` is a great shortcut (for the reasons discussed in #2)...and it would be a crime to leave it mapped to its default command: `change-input-method`.  (Maybe some of you use it a lot, I certainly don't.)
2. The following factors determine the ease and speed of a keyboard shortcut (starting with the most important):

   - *Continuously pressing the modifier key* (whatever it may be, `Ctrl`, `Meta`, etc.).  For example, it's way faster for me to hit `C-c C-l C-p` than it is to hit `C-x o`.  I personally find it very inconvenient to have to lift off the `Ctrl` key in between successive key-strokes of a given key sequence; it's so much easier just to keep mashing the modifier button (in this case, `Ctrl`).  (This specific example might be influenced by the fact that I've remapped my `Ctrl` key and my `Caps-Lock` key.)
   - *Alternation in your friend*.  It's way faster for me to hit `C-c C-l C-p` than it is to hit `C-p C-' C-;`.  (Give it a try and it should be obvious.)  Generally speaking, it's a lot easier to use keystroke sequences that use alternating hands (or, at the least, alternating fingers on the same hand).
   - *Degree of departure from standard hand position.*  This doesn't apply to the hunt-and-peck enthusiasts out there.  But for the rest of us, our most frequently used keyboard shortcuts should allow us to return to our standard touch-typing position quickly and easily.

Just a couple of thoughts that I thought might be helpful to newbies.  I may add some more later.

Answer (score 4):

I use `windmove.el` and `bs.el` to switch buffers quickly.  Both modes
are included with Emacs.

- `windmove.el` - switches to a **window** (a buffer that is currently displayed) in a specified direction,
  e.g. left, right, up, down.
- `bs.el` - I use `bs-cycle-next` and `bs-cycle-previous` to switch to
  the next buffer that isn't currently shown in a window.

You can setup windmove with `(windmove-default-keybindings)` which
will bind the appropriate commands to `Shift-Left Arrow`, `Shift-Right Arrow`, etc.

For setting up `bs.el`, something like this will work:

```
 (global-set-key [(f9)]   'bs-cycle-previous)
 (global-set-key [(f10)]  'bs-cycle-next)
```

Comment: Buffer is NOT Window (Frame)! Don't confound them!

Comment: And a window isn't a frame.  Regardless, `windmove.el` is under the EmacsWiki page "Switching Buffers", plus `bs.el` operates on buffers, not windows.

Comment: I clarified what windmove does.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer browser-style tab navigation. I have bound Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab to next and previous buffers respectively:

```
(global-set-key [C-tab] 'next-buffer)
(global-set-key [C-S-tab] 'previous-buffer)
```

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to switch buffers I'm aware of is with [`ace-jump-buffer`](https://github.com/waymondo/ace-jump-buffer). One key stroke opens the buffer menu and then select the letter next to the buffer you want with `ace-jump-line-mode`. This works best for the 26 or so most recent buffers. For switching to buffers farther back in your usage history, `ido-switch-buffer` is always a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

Widely speaking, there are 2 ways to switch buffers and most of the solutions
will fall into one of these.

1. Using the mini buffer

This is what `C-x b` does by default. Ido gives you nice auto completion so that
you don't need to TAB TAB TAB so much. Projects like helm, projectile etc makes
it easier by giving you abilities to work with files in a project etc, and along
with ido, they can be pretty useful.

2. An entire buffer with all items listed.

This is useful when you have so many buffers and you want a list of them all.
You can go up and down the buffer, and press enter to visit a particular file.
Ibuffer is pretty good for that.

I use both and this is how you can set it up.

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ido-switch-buffer)
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-x b") 'ibuffer)`
```

Comment: For the second Helm is also a nice option

Answer (score 2):

Addition to ido, I have following setup.

1. In case of evil mode, use following key bindings to switch buffers

   ```
   (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-j") 'next-buffer)
   (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-k") 'previous-buffer)
   (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-S-h") 'evil-window-left)
   (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-S-j") 'evil-window-down)
   (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-S-k") 'evil-window-up)
   (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-S-l") 'evil-window-right)
   ```
2. Set buffer name as title of window. This will help you when navigating with above keybindings

   ```
   (setq frame-title-format "%b")
   ```
3. If you are using evil mode, you can try `evil-leader`. Bind frequently used keys to leader. e.g You can bind `C-x b` to `<leader>-b`.

   ```
   (global-evil-leader-mode)
   (evil-leader/set-leader ",")
   (evil-leader/set-key
    "b" 'switch-to-buffer)
   ```
4. Bind dired mode to `C-<f8>`. Now when you want to open file in directory, press `C-<f8>`, navigate to file name & press `a` instead of `RET`. So dired buffer will be killed immediately.

   ```
   (global-set-key (kbd "C-<f8>")
           (lambda ()
             (interactive)
             (dired default-directory)))
   (put 'dired-find-alternate-file 'disabled nil)
   ```
5. Use `recentf` mode to navigate recent files. `C-x C-r`
6. One last important point is - use ergonomic mechanical keyboard. So you can press 'ctrl' key easily and quickly with wrist instead of hurting pinky.

Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the other answers, there are many ways to streamline this particular task. I personally use [Lusty Emacs](https://github.com/sjbach/lusty-emacs) as my buffer switching apparatus, as it handles fuzzy completion quite nicely. This minimizes the number of key-strokes required to select the new buffer; for example I need only type `oxr<tab>` to switch to `ox-reveal.el`, or even just `o` the second time around, as it tracks the history of switches as well.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can click the buffer name in the mode line to cycle to the next buffer.

Comment: You might like to clarify *how* to click, i.e. which buttons to use, especially since you can use that to go either to the next or to the previous buffer.

Comment: I didn't know about this until now. It's nice when you just use mouse/trackpad for whatever reason. would never believe this is possible in Emacs. Makes me wonder what else am missing. Right click move you to previous buffer.

Comment: I get a hint about the button to press when the mouse pointer is on the buffer name, in the mode line.
I use _Emacsformacosx_ on Apple Mac, not in a shell window.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised no one mentioned [iflipb](https://github.com/jrosdahl/iflipb). Much better than bare cycling through.

> iflipb provides three commands: `iflipb-next-buffer`, `iflipb-previous-buffer` and `iflipb-kill-buffer`.
>
> `iflipb-next-buffer` behaves like `Alt-TAB`: it switches to the previously used buffer, just like `C-x b RET` (or `C-M-l` in XEmacs). However, another consecutive call to `iflipb-next-buffer` switches to the next buffer in the buffer list, and so on. When such a consecutive call is made, the skipped-over buffer is not regarded as visited.
>
> While flipping, the names of the most recent buffers are displayed in the minibuffer, and the currently visited buffer is surrounded by square brackets and marked with a bold face.
>
> A key thing to notice here is that iflipb displays the buffer contents after each step forward/backwards (in addition to displaying the buffer names), unlike for instance the buffer switching model of ido-mode where only the buffer names are displayed.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please provide more detail to make your answer stand alone.  We discourage link-only answers because the links can change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just keep brushing through your buffers, add this to your init file:

```
(bind-key* "M-l" 'next-buffer)
(bind-key* "M-k" 'previous-buffer)
```

You do need the [bind-key](https://melpa.org/#/bind-key) package and you can change the key-bindings to your wish but I found these keybindings to be the most comfortable. Before adding this snippet, you do need to require bind-key by,

```
(require 'bind-key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I using C-Tab and C-S-Tab like general applications.

```
(defun change-buffer-until-normal (change-fn)
  (let (current (buffer-name))
    (funcall change-fn)
    (while (and (string-prefix-p "*" (buffer-name))
        (not (eq current (buffer-name))))
      (funcall change-fn))))

(defun my-next-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (change-buffer-until-normal 'next-buffer))

(defun my-prev-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (change-buffer-until-normal 'previous-buffer))

(global-set-key [C-tab] 'my-next-buffer)
(global-set-key [C-S-iso-lefttab] 'my-prev-buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very elegant solution (since it uses macros instead of functions) and it does not answer how to jump to **any** buffer quickly, but only how to jump to buffers used recently. But it works very well for me:

I have a series of macros using `ido-switch-buffer` to jump to the previous buffer, the buffer before that, the buffer before that, etc. And I bound those macros to key bindings that I find convenient.

To jump to the last buffer:

```
(fset 'my-goto-previous-buffer
      [?\C-x ?b return])
```

To jump to the penultimate buffer:

```
(fset 'my-goto-previous-buffer
      [?\C-x ?b ?\C-n return])
```

To jump to the antepenultimate buffer:

```
(fset 'my-goto-previous-buffer
      [?\C-x ?b ?\C-n ?\C-n return])
```

Etc. (you can ad as many `?\C-n` as you want to go as far back the history of visited buffers as you want).

There is a built-in function to jump to the previous buffer, but the advantage of using macros with `ido-switch-buffer` is that you can customize the variable `ido-ignore-buffers` to remove special buffers such as `*Messages*` or `*scratch*` and any other unwanted buffer from the list. That way, the only buffers you jump to are the ones you are really interested in jumping to.

Answer (score 0):

I see people have mentioned `ido` and `iswitchb` but oddly enough, noone mentioned `icomplete-mode` yet, which is another similar alternative.

The main difference is that instead of changing the binding of `C-x b` to some alternative command, it works by changing the way minibuffer completion works, so it affects all minibuffer completion operations rather than only buffers (or files).

In Emacs-27, there is also a variant of `icomplete-mode` called `fido-mode` which aims to mimick the `ido` UI, but again by changing the whole minibuffer completion UI so it applies "everywhere".

Answer (score 0):

There is also the package [nswbuff](https://github.com/joostkremers/nswbuff) which give you live preview of the buffer you want open.

Answer (score 0):

1. [ibuffer](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode), classic package:

   ```
   (require 'ibuffer)
   (require 'ibuf-ext)
   (defalias 'list-buffers 'ibuffer)
   (setq
    ibuffer-expert 1
    ibuffer-hidden-filter-groups (list "Helm" "*Internal*")
    ibuffer-saved-filter-groups
    '(
      ("default"
       ("Dired"
        (mode . dired-mode))
       ("Markdown"
        (mode . markdown-mode))
       ("YAML"
        (mode . yaml-mode))
       ("Org"
        (mode . org-mode))
       ;; Some
       ;; settings for buffer
       ;; grouping

       ;; Emacs standard buffers in one place
       ("Emacs"
        (or
         (name . "^\\*scratch\\*$")
         (name . "^\\*Messages\\*$")
         (name . "^\\*\\(Customize\\|Help\\)")
         (name . "\\*\\(Echo\\|Minibuf\\)")))))
    ibuffer-show-empty-filter-groups nil ;; Do not show empty groups
    ibuffer-truncate-lines nil
    ibuffer-sorting-mode 'filename/process
    ibuffer-formats ;; Columns order and size
    '(
      (
       mark
       modified
       read-only
       locked
       " "
       (mode 8 -1 :left)
       " "
       (name 30 40 :left :elide)
       " "
       filename-and-process)
      (
       mark
       " "
       (name 16 -1)
       " "
       filename))
    ibuffer-use-other-window nil)

   (defun setup-ibuffer-mode ()
     "Settings for 'ibuffer-mode'."
     (interactive)
     (hl-line-mode 1)
     (ibuffer-auto-mode 1)
     (ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups "default"))
   (global-set-key (kbd "<f2>") 'ibuffer)
   (add-hook 'ibuffer-mode-hook #'setup-ibuffer-mode)
   ```
2. [Helm](https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/) (all-in-one, ultimate package):

   ```
   (require 'helm)
   (global-set-key (kbd "<f2>" 'helm-buffer-list))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

## nim-switch-buffers

Emacs buffer switching made easy.

Wouldn't it be nice if emacs buffer switching worked like Firefox tab switching?

- Never loose the existing order.
- Control-PgUp/Dn to switch buffers in order without end.
- Shift-Control-PgUp/Dn to shift current buffer in the list.

I didn't want tabs and the mess they make on the console.
I just wanted the functionality.

## Ordered tab switching without the tabs.

I created/uploaded the code at [github.com/paulihano/nim-switch-buffers](https://github.com/paulihano/nim-switch-buffers)

Answer (score 0):

Click the buffer name in the mode-line to switch to the previous (left click) or next (right-click) buffer in the list of current buffers.

Comment: Not clear what you're saying. I'm guessing you mean clicking the buffer name **in the mode-line**. If so, please say so.

Answer (score -1):

On my VM, C-x ALT-RIGHT / LEFT is too slow. I have to wait for C-x to register in the status bar before I can do anything else. plus its just too many keys. So i mapped C-TAB and C-M-TAB to next and prev buffer as that's what I do in most windows programs anyway. Its easy to do from within emacs: 
`M-x` takes you to the status bar.
Then type `global-set-key` which will prompt you for the key sequence you wish to bind (`C-TAB`) and then for the command you wish to bind it to (`next-buffer`). That's it!

Comment: Welcome.  Other answers seem to already cover mapping these commands to other keys.

Comment: Not exactly - everyone is talking about how to change your .emacs config file. I've described how to do it from within emacs session