# void-function when loading ido-mode in Emacs24

Tags: package, use-package

I'm using Emacs 24.4.1 from Debian unstable and have added the lines from question "[How do I switch buffers quickly?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/850/2291)". However this results in an error message and I found no way to resolve it.

I can reproduce it by adding the following line into the `*scratch*` buffer:

```
(use-package ido-mode)
```

When I press <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> I get the following message:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function use-package)
  (use-package ido-mode)
  eval((use-package ido-mode) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp)
  popup-menu((keymap (new-file menu-item "Visit New File..." find-file :enable (menu-bar-non-minibuffer-window-p) :help "Specify a new file's name, to edit th$
  menu-bar-open()
  call-interactively(menu-bar-open nil nil)
  command-execute(menu-bar-open)
```

Why occurs this message and what should I do to get

Comment: I've edited your referenced answer to now show the same implementation without having to install `use-package`. I'd still recommend installing that package once you understand what that does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*use-package* is not part of standard Emacs. It's an extension you can install via the package manager from Melpa [or download direct](http://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) and as such you will need to:

```
(require 'use-package)
```

before you can use it to manage you package loads.